# Laravel: Access Rules::in variable items

Tags: laravel

How to access the items listed in an `Illuminate\Validation\Rules\In` variable ?

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\In;
$foo = Rule::in('a', 'b');
$foo->toString() // error
```

The only way I found to show it is:

```
>>> dump($foo)
Illuminate\Validation\Rules\In^ {#3512
  #rule: "in"
  #values: array:2 [
    0 => "a"
    1 => "b"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert that `Illuminate\Validation\Rules\In` to collection then take the result array:

```
$foo = Rule::in('a', 'b');
$values = collect($foo)->values()[1];
```

to get the string Representation from it:

```
$stringRepresentation=$foo->__toString();
```

Comment: Is there any arrow way to get it as well, like `$foo->someMethod()` ?

Comment: yes, there is the normal __toString() method, but it's not quite enough

Comment: Great!! thanks a lot! I saw this method but didn't understand how to use it... Why isn't quite enough ?